# How to link something when using background-image:url

Tags: html, css

Okay, so I want to link another html webpage. Like let's a user clicks on one of the images in the slider and it opens items.html. Is there a way to do this with HTML and CSS?

Html:

`<div class="slider">
</div>
</body>
</html>`

Css:

```
    .slider{
background-position: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 1200px;
    height:500px;
    border:0px;
    overflow:hidden;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;

    animation:one 30s infinite;
    position:relative;
    background-size:1200px 500px;
    transition:2s ease;
    transition-delay:2s;

    }
    @keyframes one{
    0%{background-image:url("Images/Image.png");}
    20%{background-image:url("Images/image2.png");}
    40%{background-image:url("Images/Image.png");}
    60%{background-image:url("Images/image2.png");}
    80%{background-image:url("Images/Image.png");}
    100%{background-image:url("Images/image2.png");}
    }
```

Comment: Can't you just wrap the `.slider` content inside an anchor tag and set its `href` attribute to the page you need?

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to be just one URL, then yes: just add an `onclick="window.location.href='new_url_here'"` to the DIV tag. If you want it to change where it goes to based on the image displayed, you'll need some more JavaScript. So for instance, you could have `onclick="performLink(this)"` and then this JS function:

```
function performLink(element) {
    let url;
    switch (element.style.backgroundImage) {
        case "Images/Image.png":
          url = 'http://some.url.com/first_url';
          break;
        // insert other cases here
    }
    window.location.href = url;
}
```

You could always do some more sophisticated things with it, like validate that a URL has been set (i.e. the background image was one of the ones you checked for), or use a map to look up the URLs from the image paths instead of a swtich statement, but that's the most basic idea.